# Where can I find UX documentation for Xamarin's TableView Intent?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The Xamarin TableView has an [Intent property](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.TableView.Intent/) that allows me to define between

- Data
- Form
- Menu
- Settings

However it's not clear what the UX difference will be on each platform.

Is there any elaboration for this enumeration?

Comment: "where can i find documentation" questions should not ever be downvoted, who did that?

Comment: Especially when official documentation does not provide answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (`9c48284d`) the only platform specific renderer that uses that `TableIntent` enum is on iOS.

If you set the TableView to be "Data" orientated the section headers & footers do not float in the view.

`Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/TableViewRenderer.cs`

```
~~~
if (e.NewElement.Intent != TableIntent.Data)
   style = UITableViewStyle.Grouped;
~~~
```

Comment: Thanks, outside of this, I didn't see documentation on it.  Strange this Q has downvotes and close votes... anyone with insight please share

Comment: @LamonteCristo ***Pure assumption*** on my part, but I think the intention was to provide more platform specific optimizations, like using a native Android `PreferenceFragment` if you set it to `Settings`... instead of having to mock the appearance of one in Forms but I have not seen anything in the PR/code base that suggests that is happening... (?)

Answer (score 1):

It's found at https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TableIntent/

**Data**    A table intended to contain an arbitrary number of similar data entries.

**Form**    A table which is used to contain information that would normally be contained in a form.

**Menu**    A table intended to be used as a menu for selections.

**Settings**    A table containing a set of switches, toggles, or other modifiable configuration settings.

As for specifically showing the difference between them on platforms visually, I think you'd just have to play around with them and see. Xamarin Forms Previewer does a great job at this without having to re-deploy your project to a simulator or device. (View - Other Windows - Xamarin Forms Previewer)